# How do I provide access to the library I wrap with cgo?

Tags: c, go, wrapper, accessor, cgo

I am trying to write bindings for a C library, specifically the [libnfc](http://libnfc.org). My current code is available on [Github](http://github.com/FUZxxl/openkey).

One of the central structures in the libnfc is the device. It is represented by the Go type `Device`.

```
type Device struct {
    d *C.nfc_device
}
```

All functions inside the libnfc that operate on a `Device` are methods of it. Now, there are other C libraries (e.g. the libfreefare) whose APIs operates on `nfc_device`es. For the sake of modularity, I want to place the code for each library I wrap into its own module. This leads to the problem, that I can't access private structure members from within other modules. I thought about the following solutions:

- Make `d` a public member of `Device`

  This would make it easy to access the underlying `nfc_device` from within other modules, but it makes it also easy to sidestep type safety. Additionally, I don't know whether cgo recognizes pointers to foreign types if they come from different modules. Finally, I lose flexibility if I change the structure of the Device type.
- Add an accessor `func (Device) GetCPtr() unsafe.Pointer`

  This solves the issues above but introduces the new issue that you suddently have access to an `unsafe.Pointer` in a module that might not even import `unsafe`.
- Add an accessor `func (Device) GetCPtr() uintptr`

  This solves the aforementioned issue, as you have to manually cast the result to get a proper pointer.

Are there any ways I missed? Is there a better, more idiomatic way to provide access to the underlying `nfc_device`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm generally in favour with the third proposal of yours as this is the way the [`reflect` package 
handles this issue](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Pointer).

What you could also do is to expose only an interface in your libnfc wrapper, e.g.

```
type NFCDevice interface {
    Read() ([]byte, error)
    Write() ([]byte, error)
    // ...
}
```

Now you have a public API that is safe.

Additionally, your `device` type implements a function

```
func (d *device) NfcDevice() *C.nfc_device {
    return d.nfc_device
}
```

which you can use in your other wrappers by asserting your `NFCDevice` to implement the 
interface

```
interface {
    NfcDevice() *C.nfc_device
}
```

which you can create on the fly in the other wrappers. This way a programmer has to deliberately
do something to access the inner workings of your `device`.